# How to Flatten a list to use the inner lists inside Sum

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
list = {{i,0,2},{j,0,2}};
```

I want to use the sub-lists into `Sum` as

```
sum = Sum[a[i]*b[j],{i,0,2},{j,0,2}]
```

I need to Flatten the list to get access to its all nested-sublists.

Comment: `sum = Sum[a[i]*b[j], Evaluate[Sequence @@ list]]`

Comment: Yes these are the right way. Somehow I could not find after a lot of search.